# Across the frontier means what?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

Three Pak soldiers are killed across the frontier.

What does 'across the frontier' mean?

Answer (score 1):

Without providing the original text, the best that I can assume is that another word for "frontier" would be "border":

> Three Pakistani soldiers were killed [from] across the border [with Afghanistan/Iran/India].

The killers weren't in Pakistan, they were in one of the other countries and killed them across the border.